# How do I read CPU temperatures on a Phenom II processor?

Tags: 11.04, cpu, sensors

I am trying to measure the temperature of the CPU cores on my latest ubuntu 11.04 install with kernel 2.8.32 to no avail. I have followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto to configure lm_sensors and ensured that the k10temp kernel module is installed. After running sensors-detect and everything, the output of sensors is just:

```
$ sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +28.2°C
```

Is there a way to get more detailed information about the temperature of the CPU cores?

Comment: Are you not getting critical temperature thresholds?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "acpi -t"? It shows a bunch of other temperature sensors in additional to each core.